# Как преобразовать Json в Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

Как реализовать преобразование Json в Gson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так выглядит преобразование вида из Json в Gson.

```
class Person {
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public int age;
    public Address address;
    public List<Phones> phoneNumbers;
    public List<Person> friends;
}

class Address {
    public String streetAddress;
    public String city;
    public String state;
    public int postalCode;
}

class Phones {
    public String type;
    public String number;
}
```

Теперь нужно написать:

```
Gson g = new Gson();
Person person = g.fromJson(jsonString, Person.class);
```

Здесь мы можем вытаскивать нужные данные:

```
for (Person friend : person.friends) {
    System.out.print(friend.lastName);
    for (Phones phone : friend.phoneNumbers) {
        System.out.println(" - phone type: " + phone.type + ", phone number : " + phone.number);
    }
}
```